# Unable to connect to Windows computer for file sharing

Tags: windows-networking

I have a Windows 7 machine to which I am unable to connect from several other computers.

When I try to connect to it from other Windows computers I do get the 0x80070035 error code.

I've tried the solutions described [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-networking/windows-7-network-error-code-0x80070035-windows/84791143-b70a-4ec2-b700-98df657fe45c), such as accessing the computer by IP and not by name, to no avail. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what solved my problem:
Disable password protected shared use

Control Panel, Network Center, Advance Sharing configuration, Password Protected shared use --> disable.

After trying all the solutions, that is the option that was causing trouble.

Comment: Weird enough ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is to Enable the "TCP/IP NetBIOS Helper service" , here is a link on how to do it [How to Enable TCP/IP NetBIOS Helper service](http://computerstepbystep.com/tcp_ip_netbios_helper_service.html)

And Also you can look here : [Enabling Netbios over TCP/IP on Windows 7](http://answers.ea.com/t5/Miscellaneous-Issues/Enabling-Netbios-over-TCP-IP-on-Windows-7-PC-for-Launcher-to/td-p/628082)

I hope this will fix your problem.

Comment: The TCP/IP netbios helper service was already started. And though I restarted it, I still get the error message when I try to connect to the computer.

Comment: Have you checked the TCP/IP configuration for this PC and the others ? are they in the same sub-network as yours ? could you ping to one of them ?

Comment: I can't ping to this particular machine (though I can ping from it). Same subnetwork, same Windows Workgroup.

Comment: Solved, see answer below.